# to be between apartments

Tags: expressions, prepositions, phrase-meaning

When somebody says that somebody else is between apartments, what do they mean? Take this sentence as an example: My brother lives in Chicago. At the moment he’s between apartments, so he‘s living with a friend.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a euphemistic way of saying he has no proper home of his own.  He has moved out of his old apartment, and expects to someday move into another apartment, but has not moved in yet.  "Between" is used in a temporal sense, rather than in a spatial sense.

To be "between jobs" is often a euphemism for being unemployed.

Answer (score 3):

"between girlfriends" is another variant. It makes it more obvious than you can't really be between girlfriends, since you may not ever get the future girlfriend, that is needed to bound the "between". So use of "between" is a statement of belief about the future.

Another twist on that indirect statement on the future, is when someone jokingly introduces their wonderful marriage partner as "their first wife". It's a joke about future possibilities and a brag about not needing future possibilities. As well as commentary on the typical rates of divorce.

So "between apartments" is a bit of a brag that even though one is homeless, it's no big deal, something good will happen in the future. It's casualness is both a statement of fact about where you live, and your feelings about that fact.

"homeless" doesn't convey that optimism, and also implies that the current situation is not as manageable as 'between apartments" is.

Specifically, you don't need to offer a friend money, probably.

Comment: I forget who it was attributed to, but I heard recently of some hollywood celebrity / film star / rock star who had been married several times and whilst married would describe himself as "between divorces".